# Trigger change event to trigger backbone event

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, thymeleaf

I am prefilling a form (generated from an external script). Using Jquery: `$("#first_name_1").val("test");`

When submitting the form it says that my input field is empty ..

After some research:

> onchange only fires when the user types into the input and then the input loses focus.

I tried every event (everything !): $("#first_name_1").trigger("change"), etc. ..

After some hours I saw that my form is validated with an external script using Backbone.js ... Its minified crap but I now I am here :

```
        return n.addHandler([{
        selector: "[contenteditable]",
        updateMethod: "html",
        events: ["input", "change"]
    }, {
        selector: "input",
        events: ["propertychange", "input", "change"],
        update: function (e, t) {
            console.log("88");
            e.val(t);
        },
        getVal: function (e) {
            console.log("99");
            console.log(e);
            return e.val();
        }
```

**UPDATE ->** [Link to the external Backbone.js script](https://emea3.recruitmentplatform.com/apply-app/static/apply/release/2-LATEST/apply-application-form-namespaced.js)

The application is only logging "99" when I type manually some data in the input field. But not when I use Jquery val() function...

So **How do I trigger this event in my external backbone file ??**

Many thanks for any help ...

PS: I have not any experience in Backbone.js
My application is a Spring Boot App. Frontend: Html, Semantic UI, Jquery, Thymeleaf.

**UPDATE**

I have answered my own answer ..

Comment: Based on what you have shown, someone can only suggest to try things like `$("#first_name_1").trigger("change")`, which you are already doing. Information like *"external script using Backbone.js ... Its minified crap"* won't really help to analyze why it doesn't work...

Comment: Hmja you're right. I will add a link to the full Backbone.js script. But I don't know if it make any difference ..

Comment: Don't you have access the the projects source to check what libraries are used before the build process combines and minifies the resources?

Comment: no .. The piece of code I posted, where I think the trigger must been activated,  If founded it using a beautify tool and some deep loopup ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I have received some code from externs wich works now:

**Instead of**

```
function preFillForm(){
    var gegevens = {'first_name_1':'test2 ','last_name_2':'test2 ','e-mail_address_3':'test2@test.com '};
    for(var id in gegevens){
            $("#" + id).val(gegevens[id]);
            $("#" + id).trigger("change");
    }
}
```

**I needed to do**

```
function preFillForm(){
    var gegevens = [[${gegevens}]];
    for(var id in gegevens){
        var input = $("#" + id)[0];         
        input.value = gegevens[id];
        if ("createEvent" in document) {
            var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
            evt.initEvent("change", true, true);
            input.dispatchEvent(evt);
        }
        else {
            input.fireEvent("onchange");
        }
    }
}
```

I do not really understand the difference but I'm glad it's working now.

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I had the same problem, couldn't trigger the change event to update the Backbone model. Whenever I tried to trigger the event with jQuery, nothing happened. No idea why this works, but it does.

Comment: I know Stack Overflow discourages "me too" type comments but I just have to say that I love you.  Your answer was the solution that worked for me, after a 5-hour wild goose chase.